# How to find gaps in dates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which shows the performance of a device per month. Here is how the data looks like

```
device, date, performance
   1  , 06/16, 50.4
   1  , 07/16, 54
   1  , 08/16, 6
   1  , 09/17, 67
   1  , 10/17, 56
   2  , 01/12, 34
       ....
```

A device may not be working in some months so there are some gaps in the data. For example, device one has some gaps in the above data. I'd like to create a data frame which shows the time ranges each device was working, here is how the resulting data set should look like

```
device, start, end
 1    ,  06/16, 08/16
 1    ,  09/17, 10/17
     ....
```

How can I create that using pandas?

Answer (score 3):

You can create series with the same number when consecutive months or same device. To do this, you can use `shift` and add a a month with [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html?highlight=dateoffset#dateoffset-objects) to check if the following row is a month apart. Use `cumsum` to increment the value for each new group. First you need the column 'date' as `datetime` in a series:

```
ser_date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%m/%y')
ser_group = ((((ser_date.shift() + pd.DateOffset(months=1)) != ser_date) | #month apart
              (df.device.diff() != 0)) # different device
              .cumsum()) #increment value for each group
```

Now you can use `groupby` on `ser_group`, `join` the `first` and the `last` of each group such as:

```
g_df = df.groupby(ser_group) #grouped data
df_new = (g_df['device','date'].first() #first of each group
          .join(g_df['date'].last(),rsuffix='_') #joined with last of each group
          .rename(columns={'date':'start','date_':'end'})) #rename column start/end

print (df_new)
   device   start     end
1       1   06/16   08/16
2       1   09/17   10/17
3       2   01/12   01/12
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more instructive, I extended a little your source data, so that it
contains full sets of 5 readings for 2 devices.
I also decided to change `date` column to true dates.

The concept is based on groupping by `device` and then generating
start / end dates for each group.

The script generating start / end periods can be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Source data
df = pd.DataFrame(data={ 'device': [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ],
    'date': [ '06/16', '07/16', '08/16', '09/17', '10/17',
        '03/16', '04/16', '11/16', '12/16', '01/17' ],
    'performance': [ 50.4, 54, 6, 67, 56, 50, 45, 30, 72.3, 42 ] })
# Convert date to true dates
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%y')
grp = df.groupby(by='device')
# Starts of periods
st = grp.apply(lambda x: x.date[x.date - pd.DateOffset(months = 1)
    != x.date.shift()]).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
# Ends of periods
en = grp.apply(lambda x: x.date[x.date + pd.DateOffset(months = 1)
    != x.date.shift(-1)]).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
# Result - concat start / end dates
res = pd.concat([st, en], axis=1).reset_index()
# Set column names
res.columns = ['device', 'start', 'end']
```

The result is:

```
   device      start        end
0       1 2016-06-01 2016-08-01
1       1 2017-09-01 2017-10-01
2       2 2016-03-01 2016-04-01
3       2 2016-11-01 2017-01-01
```